# EJB remote invoke lookup Weblogic - Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, weblogic, ejb-3.0

I'm new with EJB and Im trying to consume a remote EJB from Liferay. EJB is deployed on WebLogic, Im using t3 client (wlthint3client.jar).
Part of the code of EJB is:

```
Stateless(name = "myDataEJB", mappedName = "ejb/MyDataEJB",
description = "Get important Data")
@Remote({
    MyDataEJB.class,
    SecurityContext.class
})
@RolesAllowed({
    "MyRole"
})

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class MyDataEJBEJBImpl extends TheBaseSpringSecurityEJB implements MyDataEJBEJB {
//some stuff
```

And my code from Liferay is the next:

```
Properties p = new Properties(); 
p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://someip:someip,anotherip:anotherport"); 
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "some");
p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "somepass");

try {
     Context ctx = new InitialContext(p);
     MyDataEJB mydataEJB =
         (MyDataEJB)ctx.lookup("ejb/MyDataEJB#com.company.proyect.worker.ejb.MyDataEJB");
```

And I´m getting this:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'ejb.MyDataEJB#com.company.proyect.worker.ejb.MyDataEJB' didn't find subcontext 'MyDataEJB#com'. Resolved 'ejb'[Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:While trying to lookup 'ejb.MyDataEJB#com.company.proyect.worker.ejb.MyDataEJB' didn't find subcontext 'ejb.MyDataEJB#com.Resolved 'ejb'] remaining name 'ejb.MyDataEJB#com/company/proyect/worker/ejb/MyDataEJB''
```

Do you have any idea about what's happening?

Is the pattern `ejb/MyDataEJB#com.company.proyect.worker.ejb.MyDataEJB` for my lookup wrong?
Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use 
MyDataEJB mydataEJB =
         (MyDataEJB)ctx.lookup("ejb/MyDataEJB");

because your EJB is mapped by ejb/MyDataEJB in the JNDI.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm getting this Unable to resolve ejb.MyDataEJB, they are in different Server, My client and MyDataEJB, maybe is for that?